# Wrapping C++ Classes in a PHP Extension

Tags: c++, compilation, php-extension

I m following the [tutorial](http://devzone.zend.com/1435/wrapping-c-classes-in-a-php-extension/) for wrapping c++ classes in a php extension.
I m using wamp server and php 5.4.16.

something going wrong in `PHP_METHOD(Car, __construct)`.

It seems that after calling to

```
car_object *obj = ( car_object *) zend_object_store_get_object ( object TSRMLS_CC );
```

then `obj ->car` is not a valid address. when comment the line `obj ->car = car`, wamp is not shutting down. so i guess `obj ->car` is not valid or legal address.

bellow is my code:

vehicles.cc:

```
#include "php.h"
#include "car.h"

#define PHP_VEHICLES_EXTNAME  "vehicles"
#define PHP_VEHICLES_EXTVER   "0.1"

zend_object_handlers car_object_handlers;

struct car_object {
    zend_object std;
    Car *car;
};


zend_class_entry *car_ce;


void car_free_storage(void *object TSRMLS_DC)
{
    car_object *obj = (car_object *)object;
    delete obj->car; 

    zend_hash_destroy(obj->std.properties);
    FREE_HASHTABLE(obj->std.properties);

delete obj->car;
    efree(obj);
}

zend_object_value car_create_handler(zend_class_entry *type TSRMLS_DC)
{
    zend_object_value retval;

    car_object *obj = (car_object *)emalloc(sizeof(car_object));
    memset(obj, 0, sizeof(car_object));
    obj->std.ce = type;

    ALLOC_HASHTABLE(obj->std.properties);
    zend_hash_init(obj->std.properties, 0, NULL, ZVAL_PTR_DTOR, 0);

#if PHP_VERSION_ID < 50399
zval *tmp;
    zend_hash_copy(obj->std.properties, &type->default_properties,                                                                                                                                                    (copy_ctor_func_t) zval_add_ref, (void *)&tmp, sizeof(zval *));
    
    #else
        object_properties_init(&(obj->std), type);
    #endif


    retval.handle = zend_objects_store_put(obj, NULL, car_free_storage, NULL                                            TSRMLS_CC);
    retval.handlers = &car_object_handlers;

    return retval;
}

PHP_METHOD(Car, __construct)
{
long maxGear;
    Car *car = NULL;
    zval *object = getThis();

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "l", &maxGear) == FAILURE) {
        RETURN_NULL();
    }

    car = new Car(maxGear);    
car_object *obj = ( car_object *) zend_object_store_get_object(object TSRMLS_CC                 );

//obj->car = car;
```

}

```
...
...
zend_function_entry car_methods[] = {
    PHP_ME(Car,  __construct,     NULL, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC | ZEND_ACC_CTOR)
    PHP_ME(Car,  shift,           NULL, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC)
    PHP_ME(Car,  accelerate,      NULL, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC)
    PHP_ME(Car,  brake,           NULL, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC)
    PHP_ME(Car,  getCurrentSpeed, NULL, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC)
    PHP_ME(Car,  getCurrentGear,  NULL, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC)
    {NULL, NULL, NULL}
};


PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(vehicles)
{
    zend_class_entry ce;

    INIT_CLASS_ENTRY(ce, "Car", car_methods);
    car_ce = zend_register_internal_class(&ce TSRMLS_CC);
    car_ce->create_object = car_create_handler;
    memcpy(&car_object_handlers, zend_get_std_object_handlers(),                    sizeof(zend_object_handlers));
    car_object_handlers.clone_obj = NULL;
    return SUCCESS;
}

zend_module_entry vehicles_module_entry = {
#if ZEND_MODULE_API_NO >= 20010901
    STANDARD_MODULE_HEADER,
#endif
    PHP_VEHICLES_EXTNAME,
    NULL,                  /* Functions */
    PHP_MINIT(vehicles),
    NULL,                  /* MSHUTDOWN */
    NULL,                  /* RINIT */
    NULL,                  /* RSHUTDOWN */
    NULL,                  /* MINFO */
#if ZEND_MODULE_API_NO >= 20010901
    PHP_VEHICLES_EXTVER,
#endif
    STANDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES
};


ZEND_GET_MODULE ( vehicles );
```

car.h car.cc are the same as in the tutorial.

I guess that I'm missing something. maybe the call for "`object_properties_init(&(obj->std), type);`" in function `car_create_handler` is not correct..

thanks for your help/.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in your function car_free_storage, you are calling delete obj->car twice. This might not be a good idea.

Furthermore, when I was recently looking around another php module, I discovered that obj->std.properties is not always set to a valid address. So it might be worth checking if it isn't 0 before passing it to zend_hash_destroy. My code for this was:

```
if(obj->std.properties){
    zend_hash_destroy(obj->std.properties);
    FREE_HASHTABLE(obj->std.properties);
}
```